# Vuetify carousel image loading

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the vuetify's carousel to display some images. But on the first sliding, there is a white flash while transitioning, like the image was not loaded until it tries to render it.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(item,i) in items"
        :key="i"
        :src="item.src"
      ></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg',
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Demo where you can see what i'm talking about : https://codepen.io/gaalee89/pen/RwPQWXj

Is there a way to fixe this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that the eager attribute *is* part of the solution, but not the whole solution, as it only seems to apply to nested content.
Nest a v-img tag inside v-carousel-item with the eager attribute on both, then all images will preload.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(item,i) in items"
        :key="i"
        eager
      >
        <v-img :src="item.src" height="100%" eager/>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg',
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Then you need need to adjust the layout, as the image content will behave differently. height="100%" on the v-img worked for me.

Comment: It's true, just an `eager` attribute is not enough, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The above code looks fine, it is working as expected.

If you want to wait till the image loaded, use **"eager"** attribute in **"v-carousel-item"** component,

> this attribute will force the components content to render on mounted.
>   This is useful if you have content that will not be rendered in the
>   DOM that you want crawled for SEO
>
> Working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/dyodXPP

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item
        eager
        v-for="(item,i) in items"
        :key="i"
        :src="item.src"
      ></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg',
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg',
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg',
        },
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would add to the question and about eager. Eager will always load every image in your carousel which always bugged me because it will increase traffic imensly even if most of the time all you want is for it to load the images adjacent to your current one.

For this purpose (utlizing the @vue/composition-api) I usually use a class like this (it's written in typescript but I guess it should be readable for pure JavaScript users as well)

```
import { reactive, toRef, watch } from '@vue/composition-api';

export class ArrayAdjacentController<T> {
  allItems: T[];
  availableItems: T[];
  currentIndex: number;

  constructor(items: T[], placeholder?: T){
    this.allItems = items;
    this.availableItems = this.allItems.slice(0,2);
    this.currentIndex = 0;

    if(placeholder){
      for(let i=2; i<this.allItems.length; i++)
        this.availableItems.push(placeholder);
    }

    reactive(this);

    const currentIndexRef = toRef(this, 'currentIndex');

    watch(currentIndexRef, val => {
      this.setItem(val);
      this.setItem(val-1);
      this.setItem(val+1);
    });
  }

  setItem(index:number){
    if(this.allItems[index] !== this.availableItems[index])
      this.availableItems[index] = this.allItems[index];
  }

  setCurrent(number:number){
    if(number>= this.allItems.length || number < 0)
      throw new Error(`ImageDataController: ${number} out of index`);
    this.currentIndex = number;
  }
}
```

What this basically does is creating an array "availableItems" than only contains the items next to the currentIndex. So every time you hit next or prev in your carousel one more image will be loaded. Also your can use a placeholder to fill up the array (I use a data url with a 1px x 1px image in the case of v-img but you only need this if you want to use delimiters because otherwise they would not show up with the correct count). so with this class a carousel would look like this

```html
  <v-carousel v-model="internalImages.currentIndex">
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(img, ind) of internalImages.availableItems" 
      :key="ind"
      eager
    >
      <v-img
        :src="img"
        eager
      />
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
```