# Load each item after the one before is finished loading in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuetify.js, preload

I need to load around 1000 static images, .gifs, and videos for an online slideshow presentation.
Currently all items are loading at once and viewers need to wait to see the first item.
How to load each item after the one before is finished loading?

Vue.js Vuetify.js code:

```
<v-row v-for="(objkts, index) in group" :key="index">
   <v-col v-for="objkt in objkts" :key="objkt.id">
      <v-card :key="index" width="100vh">
         <v-img
            max-width="100vh"
            :src="img(objkt)"
            ></v-img>
      </v-card>
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to Alphesh's solution but I think it's a little bit easier to read. The idea is to set up a simple queueing system with three properties:

1. **imagesToLoad** - The list of images/videos you need to load
2. **loadingImage** - The image that is currently loading
3. **loadedImages** - The images that have already loaded

You'll also have a simple method called `queueNextImage` which should be called by the `mounted` hook (to start the first image loading) and then again when an image is finished loading that looks like this:

```
queueNextImage() {
  if(this.loadingImage !== null) {
    this.loadedImages.push(this.loadingImage)
  }
  this.loadingImage = this.imagesToLoad.shift()
}
```

When you start `imagesToLoad` will be populated with all the image URLs you'd like to load and `loadedImages` will be an empty array.

The template will iterate through the `loadedImages` rendering them in a regular loop and will have a single `img` element having the `src` attribute bound to the value of `loadingImage` and which fires the `queueNextImage` from the `onLoad` event of the image.

Full example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      Images to load: <span>{{imagesToLoad.length}}</span>
      Loading image: <span>{{loadingImage}}</span>
      Images Loaded: <span>{{loadedImages.length}}</span>
    </p>
    <img v-for="item in loadedImages" v-bind:key="item" v-bind:src="item" />
    <img v-on:load="queueNextImage" v-bind:src="loadingImage" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.queueNextImage();
  },
  methods: {
    queueNextImage() {
      if(this.loadingImage !== null) {
        this.loadedImages.push(this.loadingImage)
      }
      this.loadingImage = this.imagesToLoad.shift()
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    loadedImages: [],
    loadingImage: null,
    imagesToLoad: Array.from({length:200},(v,k)=>`https://via.placeholder.com/${k+850}`),
  }),
};
</script>
```

[Try it on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-darwin-c4rib?file=/src/components/Images.vue:0-819).

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

Using an image list you need to **dynamically set the src property** on each image only when the previous image is loaded

**Steps (5):**

1. Create an array of image data with image URL stored in asrc property(you can name it anything).
2. Render each image from list using v-for directive.
3. Set image src to image.src instead of asrc

> ```
> <img 
>   v-for="(image,index) in group" :key="index"
>   :src="image.src"
> ```

4. Also set an image load event to call loading of next image

> ```
> <img 
>   v-for="(image,index) in group" :key="index"
>   :src="image.src"
>   @load="loadNextimage(index)"/>
> ```

5. Whenever image loader is called then add src property to the image. This will start the image to load.

> ```
> loadNextimage(currentIndex){
>   let nextIndex = currentIndex+1
>   if( nextIndex < this.group.length){
>       let img = this.group[nextIndex]
>       img.src = img.asrc
>       delete img.asrc
>      Vue.set(this.group, nextIndex, img)
>   }
> }
> ```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
  
    return {
      group: [
          { id: 1, title: '', asrc: 'https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/120x120'},
          { id: 2, title: '', asrc: 'https://source.unsplash.com/collection/8961198/120x120'},
          { id: 3, title: '', asrc: 'https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190723/120x120'},
          { id: 4, title: '', asrc: 'https://source.unsplash.com/collection/KizanWcExgU/120x120'}
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.loadNextimage(-1)
  },
  methods:{
    loadNextimage(currentIndex){
      let nextIndex = currentIndex+1
      if(nextIndex<this.group.length){
          let img = this.group[nextIndex]
          img.src = img.asrc
          delete img.asrc
         Vue.set(this.group,nextIndex,img)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
img {
    height: 120px;
    width:120px;
}

img:not([src]){
  background: url(https://www.slntechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/ef3-placeholder-image.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <img 
      v-for="(image,index) in group" :key="index"
      :src="image.src"
      @load="loadNextimage(index)"
    >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lazy` component from vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lazy/

Wrap your code inside this component and your html will be loaded based on visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lazy will only start loading the content if it's in view, right? I need to have it loaded before. E.g. As soon as it's in view the video should be (pre)loaded and autoplay.

Comment: Oh I get you. Maybe try looking into this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211519/controlling-image-load-order-in-html

Comment: Here is another article about lazy loading techniques https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use image preloading.
If you use Nuxt.js you can load data in build time and show all assets.
Image preloading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

You can render images in lazy mode
https://css-tricks.com/lazy-loading-images-with-vue-js-directives-and-intersection-observer/

There is some example for image preloading in Vuetify
[Vuetify carousel image loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628478/vuetify-carousel-image-loading)

Or you can use this component for preloading
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want something like loading images one by one in the ascending order of the index.

You can try one approach like:

- Creating an `async` method and `await` the loading of the images in loop.

**Pseudocode Example**:

1. First replace the code in vue template

```
<v-img
    max-width="100vh"
    :src="imgCollection[index]"
></v-img>
```

2. Then load the images asynchronously one by one.

```
    async function loadImages() {
        imagesList.forEach((img, index) => {
            var data = await getImageData(img.url);
            
            // update the data into your array
            imgCollection[index] = data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain it a little further or provide an example? Where should I call the loadImages() function?

Comment: @Tom You can call loadImages method after your page is loaded or the component is mounted, it'll automatically update the images.